# When does UI (as opposed to widget toolkit type thing) need to know screen dimensions?

Tags: security, user-interface, web, privacy

In a secure OS, we'd like to not tell applications anything unless they absolutely must know. Say you browse a website through an anonymity network as two different identities by running separate isolated instances of the web browser. The web browser instances can transmit your screen size, and then an adversary could see that both of your identities use the same screen size and make a more accurate guess that they are the same person. Screen size reveals identity or narrows it down.

What are some use cases of why a UI/web page (as opposed to the underlying technology) needs your screen size? Why not just use abstract dimensions for everything? Or use layout widgets that don't let you even touch dimensions. What are the limitations of these techniques?